# Accessing first Object and an arrays inside it

Tags: javascript, angular6

I know im not suppose to use map because because i cant iterate through an object. i just have no idea what to use to go through the fist object aod.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.chartsService.getAOD().subscribe(data => {
    (this.data as any) = data;
    console.log(this.data);
    this.data.map(values => {
      console.log(values);
    });
  });
  this.chartOptions();
}
```

[image]

Comment: You want to retrieve the value of `aod` property, right? Which is an array of two objects

Comment: im aware of that thats why i mentioned it on my post. i just need assistance with unwrapping the object

Comment: Have you tried to chaining dot notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three static methods on Object provide iterables from objects

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.chartsService.getAOD().subscribe(data => {
    (this.data as any) = data;
    Object.entries(this.data).map(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value));
    Object.keys(this.data).map((key) => console.log(key));
    Object.values(this.data).map((value) => console.log(value));
  });
  this.chartOptions();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the aod field you have to do the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.chartsService.getAOD().subscribe(data => {
     (this.data as any) = data;
     console.log(this.data);
     this.data.aod.forEach(values => {
       console.log(values);
     });
  });
this.chartOptions();
}
```

In typescript for access to a public field inside an object you just have to type object.fieldname, and for iterate over an Array, you can use forEach function.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript .map method only available for Array but current this.data variable data type as object. You can convert Object into Arra Or use ForEach or For loop